# Abrir dos veces un file con php y cerrar una vez

Tags: php, fopen

Estoy intentando hacer un contador de visitas con un archivo de texto, el codigo es este:

```
<?php
$file = "counter.txt";
$access = fopen($file, "r+");
$counter = fread($access,filesize($file));
$counter++;
fwrite(fopen($file, "r+"), $counter);
fclose($access);
?>
```

Para que los caracteres no se acumulen en el archivo, tengo que abrirlo dos veces, porque si en vez de eso uso la variable `$access` en `fwrite()`, se acumulan los caracteres. Mi interrogante es si al abrirlo dos veces, ¿ocupa el doble de espacio en la ram o la segunda sobreescribe a la primera?; o bien, en caso de que ocupe dos veces la memoria, ¿tengo que usar `fclose()` dos veces, o una sola vez cierra todas las aperturas del archivo?.

Comment: No deberías preocuparte por la cantidad de memoria usada, porque solo almacenas un dato. El problema real es que no es muy viable usar archivos; en cuanto tengas dos o más usuarios ingresando al mismo tiempo, lo más probable es que obtengas errores (archivo inexistente o bloqueado). Es mucho más conveniente usar base de datos.

Comment: Ya hice la prueba experimental con mi pc y mi telefono y no se bloquean, porque un archivo de texto lo puedes abrir y despues borrarla, y la ventana sigue ahi abierta. Pero en cuanto a lo que me dices, entonces ¿quiere decir que aunque se abra dos veces no ocupa el doble de memoria? Eso es lo que te entiendo

Comment: Hace más de 10 años usé contadores con archivos de texto y dejaron de ser funcionales en cuanto la web recibía unos pocos visitantes al día, entre 50 y 100, que no es gran cosa. En cuanto a la memoria, solo digo que la cantidad usada es mínima, ya sea que se duplique o no... no es relevante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

deberías poder sobre escribir la variable en la que haces la lectura:

```php
// inicialización
$file = "counter.txt";
$access = fopen($file, "r+");

// sección 1
$counter = fread($access,filesize($file));
$counter++;
fwrite(fopen($file, "r+"), $counter);

// sección 2
$counter = fread($access,filesize($file));
$counter++;
fwrite(fopen($file, "r+"), $counter);

//cierre
fclose($access);
```